# System.IO.Pipelines Socket.ReceiveAsync(Socket, Memory<Byte>) vs PipeReader.Create(Socket.GetStream())

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server, system.io.pipelines

With `System.IO.Pipelines` you can read and parse data from a socket either by:

- Creating a `Pipe` and filling it with a `PipeWriter` Task that directly receives from a socket with `Socket.ReceiveAsync()` and using another `PipeReader` Task to parse the data from the pipe.

**OR**

- Use a `PipeReader` Task directly on the `NetworkStream` from the socket to parse the data directly from the stream with `PipeReader.Create(new NetworkStream(Socket)))`

Is one way more performant than the other, or is the performance difference negligible?

Comment: Written long before the `Pipelines` library, but no less relevant: [which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: Pipes were created to *bypass* the NetworkStream and read bytes at a lower level while reusing buffers. You should expect that using pipes directly would be faster and allocate less simply because there's no NetworkStream in the middle. To see the actual difference though you should benchmark this

Comment: @JeroenMostert That was a great read, I definitely have a habit of focusing on "always finding the best approach no matter what." Sometimes it's not even necessary and my time could be used focusing on other things.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your response, I thought that was most likely the case. I will continue to use the Pipe approach without the stream for now. I will probably end up benchmarking the two at some point, because I am curious how much of a difference it makes.